# Developing with Composer path repository and merge plugin, how to avoid update of composer.lock?

Tags: git, composer-php, development-environment, dependency-management

Here is the situation.

I'm developing *package-a* which depends on *package-b*. The latter is hosted on bitbucket:

```
projects/
├── package-a/
├── package-b/
```

**I need to make changes to *package-b* and see the results without pushing the code and do a `composer update`.** Then, when finishing the work, I'll push a new tag and deploy *package-a* to the production server.

So I ended up using [composer-merge-pluging](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) and [Composer path repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path), with the following configuration:

Here is the `composer.json` of *package-a*:

```
{
    "name": "my/package-a",
    "require": {
        "my/package-b": "^1.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:my/package-b.git"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "composer.local.json"
            ]
        },
        "replace": true
    }
}
```

This file will include `composer.local.json` (only in my local machine! this file is not committed nor pushed to the production server), where I'm saying "use the dev-master version and the path repository":

```
{
    "require": {
        "my/package-b": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url":  "../package-b"
        }
    ]
}
```

The setup is fine in the sense that if I run `composer install` from *package-a* then *package-b* is symlinked and I can work directly on it.

But when I deploy *package-a* to my server using [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) (versioning the `composer.lock` file too) it does a `composer install` but lock file contains a reference to *package-b@dev-master* using the path repository (and this is wrong).

Any idea how to solve this problem? I'm sure it's a common one but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

To aide in development of packages, you can have [composer install the source of `package-b` instead of the distribution](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update).

Inside `package-a`:

```
rm -rf vendor/package-b
composer update --prefer-source package-b
```

This should do a clone of `package-b` into the `vendor` directory. From there, you can make the changes in `vendor/package-b` and see the changes reflected inside the current application (`package-a`).

When you're happy with the changes in `package-b`, you can commit the changes off. Your work with `package-b` will be done.

Before deploying `package-a`, you'll want to make sure that the commit for `project-b` that is referenced in your `composer.lock` file has been pushed up to the remote (bitbucket you said) and is up to date.

You may end up not even needing a separate checkout of `project-b` at all. Do any needed work *inside* of `project-a`. (Just a possibility)

---

One thing that will make your life remarkably easier will be to start tagging releases of your packages.

Rather than chasing separate moving targets, start thinking of the features you need to add to `package-b` to make the new functionality in `package-a` work... add in that functionality, and release it. Then your work with `package-a` is "update to the new release of `package-b` so I can use cool new functionality `x`"

It'll help your release process, improve feature planning, and generally make for a cleaner experience.